# Find pixel mapping matrix with minimum iterations

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

**The Situation**
 I am an electronics engineer and on a volunteer team that have built a prototype eye that has 200*200 sensors that are mapped to the optic nerve, the connection to the optic nerve is random (organic connection is grown) so I need to have the patient draw what they see, I am trying to limit the number of drawings (difficult for a blind person) the patient has to do to get the relationship between the artificial eye output and the correct perception of the image.

**The Problem**
Given a input image/matrix and an viewable/readable output matrix, **what is an algorithm to automatically identify the encoding  with the least number of iterations.**

[image]

By changing the input one pixel at a time and then examining the output, the relationship can be discovered, this is, however, very inefficient.

Comment: The answer to the question is "yes, there is such an algorithm".  Hint: given the above example, you can do it with 6 queries.

Comment: @AnthonyKeane: this isn't a C writing service.  I would suggest instead that you think about the problem; if you were given a 2x2 array, how can you do it with 2 queries?  Then, if you were given a 4x4 array, how can you do it with 4 queries?  If you can answer those two questions, generalizing it to nxn arrays should be easy.

Comment: How do you represent the "encoding"? Is this to calibrate the software with some known images? If arbitrary mappings are allowed, it's unlikely that one letter is enough to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

Number the pixels from $0$ to $n^2-1$. Then create $\lceil \log_2n^2\rceil$ many pictures. In the $i$-th picture all pixels are black, if the $i$-th bit in their number is $1$, white otherwise.

Note: If you have $2^k$ colors available, you can choose the color for each pixel based on $k$ successive bits of the number. This will reduce the number of images by a factor of $k$.

Comment: huh - how does apply in code?

Comment: @AnthonyKeane I don't mean to be rude, but I doubt you will find someone on here to write the code for you. You mention this is a volunteer team. Check with a local university and see if they will send out an email to their computer science, EE, and computer engineering students to see if anyone wants to volunteer their time to write the code for you.

Comment: @mikeazo so it appears

Comment: Unfortunately this approach won't work since a human almost certainly won't be able to draw pixel correct 200x200 images.